# CLI E-Mail client with auto reply?

Tags: email, software-rec

All I can find online refers to a setup where you own the mailserver. This is **not** the case here.

I have a **headless** (so thunderbird is a no go) machine (ARM) on which I need to setup an automated mail reply client. The mail service I am using does not have such a feature. I can access my mails using the IMAP protocol, and send mails using the SMTP protocol.

[reply-o-matic](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rom) seems similar to what I want, but unless I get it wrong it only works when the mailserver is installed on the machine.

I've also found [vacation](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/uvacatio.htm) but again, all the setup tutorials I come across mention a setup with "postfix", which is a mailserver, so not the kind of setup I need.

Can someone point me to a CLI mail **client** that supports such feature?

Comment: Do you want to automatically reply to all e-mails forever or just some e-mails, for example filtered by sender or subject etc.?

Comment: There doesn't have to be any filtering of any sorts. Just any mail that comes in should be replied to for as long as the tool is running. It *would* be a benefit though if there was a filter by sender domain or part of subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have now solved this the easy (yet a bit resource intensive) way, using VNC and thunderbird.

Here's a step by step guide which was performed on a headless debian machine:

**1. Install a graphical environment**

I wanted the absolute most lightweight system there is. `xfce4` shocked me with its many dependencies (total disk space would've been 474MB for me with 266 new packages). `lxde` came in even worse at 579MB at 384 packages.

I decided to go with `icewm` - Which technically isn't a full desktop environment but a standalone window manager. 268MB at 117 packages.

```
sudo apt-get install icewm
```

**2. Install the VNC server**

`tightvnc` is a very lightweight, fast, easy to setup VNC server that automatically creates a virtual desktop, so perfect to run on a headless machine.

```
sudo apt-get install tightvncserver
```

**3. Create a new user for the VNC server**

This is optional, but I wanted to keep things as tidy as possible.

```
sudo adduser vnc
```

Enter a desired password, you can keep the other questions blank.

**4. Start the VNC server**

First, log into the new account, then start the VNC server.

```
su - vnc
vncserver
```

As simple as that! It will ask you for a password you need to login.

To connect to your VNC server you can use any VNC viewer you like, there's even plenty on your smartphone's appstore. I went with `vinagre` on my desktop. You simply connect to it by using the servers IP and the default port `5901`.

**5. Install thunderbird and set-up auto-reply**

```
sudo apt-get install thunderbird
```

This is a bit heavy on resources (26 packages for me, 184MB) but it makes the setup of automatically replying to mails a very easy task.

Open thunderbird within the VNC desktop, choose to use your existing email and log into your email account using IMAP.

Next we need to create a templete for our out-of-office reply. Hit the `Write` button on the top, and write your message and subject as you'd like. Once done, go to `File -> Save As -> Template`. The template name will be your subject.

Now hit the menu button and go to `Message Filters -> Message Filters`. Inside that window, click on `New` on the right. Here you can give your filter a name (e.g. `Out of office`). You can keep the `Apply filter when` settings at default, or change it to `Filter after Junk Classification` if you'd like.

Here you can further set specific filters you would like, for example to black- or whitelist specific senders or subjects. If you don't want any filter, select `Match all messages`.

On the bottom actions now select `Reply with Template` and select your template. That's it! Optionally you can add another action to mark the message as read aswell, but I won't do that so I know what I have to manually check/reply to later. You could also have the message tagged so you will easily know later which messages an auto-replied has been given to, if you used filters above.

Simply hit `OK` now. Using the `Enabled` checkbox you can turn it on or off.

**You're done!**

Don't forget to simply disconnect the VNC session, leaving thunderbird open, as logging out would terminate thunderbird. Consider the use of filters to avoid spam or similar if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

[Mutt](http://mutt.org) is a Mail User Agent (MUA); basically, a powerful email client for the terminal, (See also: [NeoMutt](https://neomutt.org)). It can use [shell scripts](https://gitlab.com/muttmua/mutt/wikis/MuttFaq/Misc#how-to-trigger-a-script-on-new-mail) as filters for [new emails](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#new-mail-command). I personally have never done exactly what you are asking for, but here are a few commands that might help.

To send an email, run `echo "This is the message body" | mutt -c <cc_address> -s "This is the subject" <to_address>`. Hint: the body can also be a file on disk, `mutt -c <cc_address> -s "Subject" <to_address> < body.txt`, (See: [Man Page](http://mutt.org/doc/mutt.1.txt) for more info).

So to clarify, you will need to 1) Create a new email script to parse incoming mail, 2) Create a script to send your response, and then 3) Set to run on cron.

Also, by default, your credentials are stored in plain text. However, if you have [GPG](https://gnupg.org) setup, you can encrypt your credentials so that they can be stored securely, (See: [dotfiles/.mutt/muttrc](https://gitlab.com/lramage/dotfiles/blob/master/.mutt/muttrc) for an example).

Comment: I looked into Mutt already, but all I found was [this](https://mutt-users.mutt.narkive.com/iIalaYVQ/auto-reply) which basically says it isn't possible. That's from 2002 though but I wasn't able to find any current info. Given the content of your link, it seems like they added that possibility with Mutt 1.6 introduced in 2016. I'll read thorugh the pages you've linked, but I would appreciate it a lot if you would add an example on how to setup the first step of utilizing the filter. Judging from a quick read it seems like Mutt will call the script on new mail, so what would I need cron for?

Comment: Well, you could either A) Open mutt at specified intervals to check for new mail, or B) Launch mutt via init script and run in the background as a daemon?

Comment: B) sounds like the better way to me. Can you add an example on how to set that up? The manual is pretty confusing on how you would go on about an exact setup for that rather seemingly simple task.